# Opencart 2.3.0.2 - multidomain multilanguage and multicurrency

Tags: opencart, currency, multilingual, opencart2.3

I'm looking for solution to change default language and currency depending on domain using pure php code. I've notice that changes are made using Ajax, but I need to make this using if domain = default currency / default language else .....

EDIT: Two domains pointing to one service, in PA I've configured to use on second domain other language and currency but not working.

Thanks for advice !

Answer (score 0):

OpenCart contains functions to use multi language and multi currency. You are able to use domain pointers in DirectAdmin for the multidomain part, if you want to use different databases you'll need to change the index.php for a bit, otherwise it's pritty easy.

**Example for different databases**

```
$host   = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$host_parts = array_reverse(explode('.', $host));
$customer = $host_parts[2];

define('NAME_CUSTOMER', $customer);
define('DIR_CUSTOMER', $customer . '/' );
define('DIR_IMAGE', DIR_PATH . 'image/' . DIR_CUSTOMER );

define('HTTP_SERVER', str_replace(CORE_SUB_DOMAIN, $customer, HTTP_SERVER_BASE));

define('HTTPS_SERVER', str_replace(CORE_SUB_DOMAIN, $customer, HTTPS_SERVER_BASE));


if (!file_exists ( DIR_IMAGE)){
    header('Location:' . URL_FALLBACK);
    exit; 
}

define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysqli');
define('DB_HOSTNAME', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', '---');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '---');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'opencart_' . $customer);
define('DB_PORT', '3306');
define('DB_PREFIX', 'oc_');
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for post, but this is not a problem. Two domains - one service. Everything configured correctly, but second domain language doesn't work as well as currencies on this domain. I've found temporary solution - it is working, but not as way it should I think. If no-one helps to make this more pro I share my code for feature :-)